# ¿Cómo poner objetos dentro de un arreglo?

Tags: javascript, array, objeto

necesito una ayuda. tengo un arreglo de objetos, de las cuales he extraído los objetos que necesito, esos objetos requiero ponerlos dentro de un nuevo arreglo, pero usando el método .push() me da un numero como resultado. Me gustaría saber de que manera puedo hacerlo.

````
```
const myObject = [
    {
    name: 'Angel',
    email: 'Angel@gmail.com',
    channel: 'tiktok',
    jobi: { read: 'Terror', movies: 'Marvel' }
    },
    {
    name: 'Miguel',
    email: 'miguel@gmail.com',
    channel: 'youtube',
    jobi: { read: 'Terror', movies: 'Marvel' }
    },
    {
    name: 'Daniel',
    email: 'daniel@gmail.com',
    channel: 'instagram',
    jobi: undefined
    }
];

for (let i = 0; i < myObject.length; i++) {
    let result = [];
    if (myObject[i]["jobi"] !== undefined) {
        console.log(result.push(myObject[i]));
    }
}
//Salida
>1
>1
```
````

El resultado que me da de esa manera es 1 1, cuando solo coloco myObject[i] dentro del console.log me da los  primeros objetos que requiero, ahora necesito que esos objetos estén dentro del array result.

Comment: declaras `result = []` en cada iteración. Decláralo una sola vez antes del for. Push retorna la cantidad de elementos, por eso siempre obtienes 1

Answer (score 3):

Lo primero es lo que te dijo @ffflabs, debes declarar result fuera porque sino lo estarias redeclarando en cada iteracion del for, y si lo que quieres es meter el objeto perteneciente a cada jobi, esta es la manera:

```js
const myObject = [
    {
    name: 'Angel',
    email: 'Angel@gmail.com',
    channel: 'tiktok',
    jobi: { read: 'Terror', movies: 'Marvel' }
    },
    {
    name: 'Miguel',
    email: 'miguel@gmail.com',
    channel: 'youtube',
    jobi: { read: 'Terror', movies: 'Marvel' }
    },
    {
    name: 'Daniel',
    email: 'daniel@gmail.com',
    channel: 'instagram',
    jobi: undefined
    }
];

let result = [];
for (let i = 0; i < myObject.length; i++) {
    if (myObject[i]["jobi"] !== undefined) {
        result.push(myObject[i].jobi);
    }
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que entiendo se quiere descartar a los objetos que su propiedad `jobi` no tengan 'nada'.

Si es asi, se puede hacer lo siguiente:

```
let result = myObject.filter((obj) => obj.jobi !== undefined);
console.log(result);
```

El resultado que me dio fue:

```
[ { name: 'Angel',
    email: 'Angel@gmail.com',
    channel: 'tiktok',
    jobi: { read: 'Terror', movies: 'Marvel' } },
  { name: 'Miguel',
    email: 'miguel@gmail.com',
    channel: 'youtube',
    jobi: { read: 'Terror', movies: 'Marvel' } } ]
```

Espero ayude, saludos.